# Copy Merged Cells and the whole row in excel-macro

Tags: vba, excel

Good Morning Programming Gurus! I am beginner at excel-macro's or vba.
I have a problem in copying the excel merged cells also in getting its whole row.

So this is my Code in Getting the First Column of the first sheet and transfer it to another sheet.

```
Sub cmdCopy()


Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long, xNumber As Integer

lastrow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 5 To lastrow

Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Copy
erow = Sheet4.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Sheet2.Paste Destination:=Sheet4.Cells(erow, 1)

Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Also I wanted to Sort it by the Column Date but i dont know how to perform it. this is the actual photo of excel file.

**[This is where the rows will get]**

[image]

**[And this one is the destination of the rows]**

[image]

I know someone out there has a capability to do this. Please Guys, Help me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: This should copy a cell you have in the first range (sheet2) and paste it at the end of your column in the next sheet (sheet4), then go back to the next cell in Sheet2 and put it after the cell that you just pasted into in Sheet4, so the loop will go though every cell you want in Sheet2 and paste it into Sheet4.

```
Sub cmdCopy()  
    Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long, xNumber As Integer  
    lastrow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row  
    For i = 5 To lastrow  
        erow = Sheet4.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row  
        Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Copy Sheet4.Cells(erow, 1)  
        'the copy method can have a destination typed right after it, so Excel  
        'takes Sheet4.Cells(row, 1) as the implied destination range.  
    Next i  
    Application.CutCopyMode = False  
    Range("A1").Select  
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the xNumber? :)

Comment: Also I need to know how to copy a merged cell and paste it in merged cell in new sheet.